# How to find in dataframe when all columns have values, remove everything before that point and then interpolate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I had a dataframe like this:

```
             time  Throttle   Vout
0      1056.65785      1      None
1      1056.66255      2      None
2      1056.66785      None   9
3      1056.67330      4      None
4      1056.67840      None   15
```

I want to remove everything before BOTH columns have had at least one value present but interpolate from the value that will be removed.
I would end with something like this:

```
             time  Throttle   Vout
0      1056.66785      2      9
1      1056.67330      4      9
2      1056.67840      4      15
```

### I'm assuming it would be something like this:

1. Find the index of when both columns have had at least one value (x)
2. Interpolate the data
3. remove everything before x

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can try:

```
cols = ['Throttle','Vout']
out = df.ffill().bfill()[df[cols].isna().cumsum().prod(1).gt(0)].copy()
```

---

```
         time  Throttle  Vout
2  1056.66785       2.0   9.0
3  1056.67330       4.0   9.0
4  1056.67840       4.0  15.0
```

Where `df[cols].isna().cumsum().prod(1).gt(0)` evaluates if both the columns have atleast 1 value:

```
df[cols].isna().cumsum().prod(1).gt(0)

0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
4     True
dtype: bool
```